# Jmeter: Response Assertion - How do I assert that the response contains a variable name

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter. I need to write an assertion to my http request. The HTTP request returns all the tags available as an array in JSON response and I need to assert that my tag, which I have stored as a variable, is part of the response

I have tried using
${tagName}

as well as
vars.get("tagName")

for response assertion, but both are doing the string match rather than matching the variable value.I am sure there is an easy fix to this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In case of "normal" [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as per [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps) article:

> The most commonly used assertion is the Response Assertion, which checks whether a response text/body/code/message/header contains, matches, or equals a specified pattern.

> The Pattern can be either be:

> - a “string” for “Equals” or “Substring” clauses
> - a “Perl5-style” Regular Expression for “Contains” or “Matches” clauses

So the configuration you're looking for is "Substring" pattern matching rule and should be something like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding. I was using 'Contains' matching rule and getting error. However using substring matching rule also gives the same error:Assertion failure message:Test failed: text expected to contain /${tagName}/

Comment: It means that your `tagName` variable doesn't have a value so double check the way you're creating/assigning it. You can see all JMeter Variables with their respective values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the JSON Assertion item, rather than the Response Assertion?

You can then assert that the JSON path in the response exists and is set to a value, which can be a JMeter variable.

Your JSON path in it might be something like $.tagName (or whatever the field is called in the response) and the expected value might be ${tagName} (your variable).

Comment: Sadly, the response doesn't have a key value pair structure, just an array of values..
{"results":["AAbb7","AFC_s2s_CRUD_NB_T4","Aztest1","Aztest2","Aztest3","CLOUD_RSSERVER2012.SIMULATION00001","Cloud_BA:ACTIVE.1","Cloud_BA:CONC.1","Cloud_BA:LEVEL.1","Cloud_BA:PHASE.1","Cloud_BA:TEMP.1","Cloud_Cloud_QA-SECD-HIST-FN.Simulation00001","Cloud_Cloud_QA-SECD-HIST-FN.Simulation00002","Cloud_Cloud_QA-SECD-HIST-FN.Simulation00003"]}